# Minimum Entropy for a given mean

Tags: information-theory, entropy

> For a given mean $1/\lambda$, find the minimum entropy among distributions that are continuous with support $\mathbb{R}^{+}\cup \{0\}$.

If we were looking for a maximum, the answer was exponential distribution. But, for a minimum, I don't know. Another way might be lower bounding differential entropy as a function of its mean, but I cannot find such a lower bound. Any idea?

Comment: You should be able to show that it diverges to $-\infty$ - consider the following parametric family of densities - pick a small $\varepsilon, \delta > 0,$ and a large $\eta$. Put a unifrom distribution with height $\varepsilon$ from $x = 0$ up to $x = 1/\lambda - \delta.$ From $1/\lambda - \delta$ to $1/\lambda + \delta$ put a triangle with total area $(1 - 2\varepsilon),$ and after $1/\lambda + \delta,$ put an exponential density with max height $\varepsilon$ and decay rate $\eta.$

Comment: You can choose $\varepsilon, \delta, \eta$ to make the mean work out correctly - this is only one constraint. Further, you should be able to show that as $\varepsilon \to 0,$ the entropy of the resulting distribution goes to $-\infty,$ which finishes the argument. I don't know if a distribution satisfying your conditions that attains $-\infty$ exists, though (this construction just shows that the infimum is $-\infty,$ and not that it is attained).

Comment: The intuition as to why it should be $-\infty$ is that you're trying to minimise a concave function that is unbounded from below. The construction I specified just uses the fact that the differential entropy of a point mass is $-\infty,$ and tries to just attach enough extra structure around the standard sequence of distributions converging to a point mass to manage the further conditions of continuity and known mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stochasticboy321's comments, there is no lower bound, you can obtain a differential entropy as low as you wish (towards $-\infty$)  by choosing a random variable that is almost constant, i.e. a (continous) density that is near a Dirac delta $f_X(x)=\delta(x-\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the desired mean.

For a concrete example, you can take a [Log-normal](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogNormalDistribution.html) with parameters $(M,S)$. Its mean is $\mu = \exp(M + S^2/2)$   and its entropy $h= \log( S e^M \sqrt{2 \pi e}) $ . Then, by taking $S>0$ arbitrarily small we can find an apt $M$ (bounded, around $\log(\mu)$) that gives the desired mean, and the entropy tends towards $-\infty$.